# how to import java code output into excel sheet without using Wamp server(Data base)?

Tags: java, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape data from a website. I want to store my output into the excle sheet without using any local database like MySQL or oracle.

Comment: What part are you having a problem with?  The scraping or the storage?

Comment: how to store results in excel sheet?

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far or if you have followed any particular approach? There are tons of libraries available for storing data in excel sheet choosing one depends on your requirement and approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a Database you can always manually create a .csv (comma separated values) file that excel can read.  The rules of a .csv file can be found on this wikipedia article.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

an example below...

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",,5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```